# adding of graphic Class object in netbean JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i am adding graphic class object "g" in JFrame class in Netbeans. but error are occurring as 
"non static variable g can not be referenced from a static context"
following are code of graphic class (just drawing a rectangle)

```
public class grafix extends JComponent {

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) (Graphics) g;
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(15,10,200,300);
g2.draw(r);
}
}
```

and
following are object adding line in Main() of JFrame class.

```
new JFrame().getContentPane().add(g);
```

object "g" been declared in JFrame class. Since i am using Netbean that why i have to use getContentPane().add() instead of JFrame.add();

Comment: The line `new JFrame().getContentPane().add(g);` is certainly wrong. You should post the code where you are declaring the `g` variable, and where you try to use it.

Comment: i am declaring g object at Jframe class by following way 

public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    grafix g ;
    public JFrame() {
        g = new grafix();
        initComponents();
         
    }

Comment: If I had to find a perfect way to confuse people, I would call my class `JFrame` and talk about "grafix", so that nobody ever knows whether I'm talking about a `javax.swing.JFrame` or a `java.awt.Graphics` or about my own classes. **Don't do this**. However, from the code posted so far it is nearly impossible to guess what the problem is. You should probably try to create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , then people will quickly be able to help you.

Comment: hahaha..don,t be confuse. i will find another way. stay cool and be happy .